# How to add category and subcategory link list to template

Tags: magento-1.8

There are some days i try to find a working solution with magento 1.8

Please, i need to know how to create an expanded link list with all categories and subcategories. `<ul><li>` list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to create child block instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and then use the `renderCategoriesMenuHtml` method of this class to output complete categories tree as a list.